# Set range for Java attributes in a class?

Tags: java, class, integer

Is is possible to set a range for Integers in a Java class?

```
public class Date {
 int year; //1900 to 2100
 int month; //1 to 12
 int day; //1 to 31
}
```

So you can only set a year between 1900 and 2100, etc. I am not supposed to use any methods to check if valid.

Comment: You need to clarify your requirements. **Setting** Java class attributes is done with a constructor or a setter. Adding validation in a setter seems perfectly reasonable and is the way to ensure an instance has valid state. Also there are already ***multiple*** Java `Date` classes. **Please** don't write another one.

Answer (score 2):

You can validate in the constructor of the class. When you try to create the class with any invalid fields an exception will be thrown.

```
Date(int year, int month, int day) {
    
    if (year < 1900 || year > 2100) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Year is out of range. Valid range is [1900-2100].");
    } else {
        this.year = year;
    }

    if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Month is out of range. Valid range is [1-12].");
    } else {
        this.month = month;
    }

    if (day < 1 || day > 31) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Day is out of range. Valid range is [1-31].");
    } else {
        this.month = month;
    }
}
```

You can test with the following to see the exceptions being thrown.

```
    Date validDate = new Date(1900, 2, 30);
    Date invalidYear = new Date(1899, 1, 30);
    Date invalidMonth = new Date(1900, -1, 3);
    Date invalidDay = new Date(1900, 8, 32);
```

Comment: This only makes sense if `year`, `month` or `day` are `final` (or `private` without any accessors), otherwise they could be modified after the fact.

Comment: Yes, when a field is public, it can be accessed and modified directly by external classes, and there's no way to intercept those changes to apply validation.

Comment: Or make it immutable by defining the class as a [record](https://openjdk.org/jeps/395). `record Date ( int year, int month, int day ) {}`

Answer (score 0):

The [Answer by Sexton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77548667/642706) is correct.

### *Jakarta Validation*

Additionally, you can use the [*Jakarta Validation*](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/bean-validation/) framework to validate your state. (Formerly known as *Java Bean Validation*, and as *Jakarta Bean Validation*.)

To quote the documentation:

> Jakarta Validation provides an object level constraint declaration and validation facility for the Java application developer, as well as a constraint metadata repository and query API.

Usage is quite simple. You can apply annotations to fields and arguments.

```
public class Date {
    @Min( 1900 )
    @Max( 2100 )
    int year;
    …
```

Then you execute a validation operation to see if current state satisfies those constraints.

Several validations are bundled with the only implementation of the current specification, [*Hibernate Validator*](http://hibernate.org/validator/) by Red Hat. You can then write more validations, and assign them to your own annotations.

You may choose to bypass the Jakarta Validation API, and instead directly use the broader product-specific API of *Hibernate Validator*.

See project site: [BeanValidation.org](http://beanvalidation.org/). See [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bean_Validation) (not up-to-date).

Answer (score 0):

> *"... Is is possible to set a range for Integers in a Java class? ..."*

No, it is not part of the syntax.

Utilize a *[class structure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)*.

```java
abstract class RangedInt {
    int a, b, value;

    RangedInt(int a, int b, int value) {
        if (value < a || value > b)
            throw new ValueOutOfBounds();
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.value = value;
    }

    static class ValueOutOfBounds extends RuntimeException {
    }
}

class Year extends RangedInt {
    Year(int value) {
        super(1900, 2100, value);
    }
}

class Month extends RangedInt {
    Month(int value) {
        super(1, 12, value);
    }
}

class Day extends RangedInt {
    Day(int value) {
        super(1, 31, value);
    }
}
```

```java
class Date {
    Year year; //1900 to 2100
    Month month; //1 to 12
    Day day; //1 to 31
}
```

Here is an example.

```java
Date d = new Date();
d.year = new Year(1234);
d.month = new Month(5678);
d.day = new Day(90);
```

Output

```
Exception in thread "main" RangedInt$ValueOutOfBounds
    at RangedInt.<init>(Example.java:18)
    at Year.<init>(Example.java:30)
    at Example.main(Example.java:6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since a valid day depends on the `month`, I suggest you use [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).  In fact, you should be using the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes for date/time requirements.

```
validate(6, 30, 2102);
validate(6, 31, 2023);
```

prints

```
Year is out of range. Valid range is [1900-2100].
Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 31
```

Method

```
public static void validate(int month, int day, int year) {
    if (year < 1990 || year > 2100) {
        System.out.println(
                "Year is out of range. Valid range is [1900-2100].");
        return;
    }
    try {
        LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of(month, day, year);
    } catch (DateTimeException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

If you really want to grow your own, then you should validate the day for the month as follows.  This also includes the adjustment for leap year.

```
int maxDay = switch(month) {
    case 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 -> 31; // months with 31 days
    case 4,6,9,11 -> 30;        // months with 30 days
    case 2 -> {                 // special case for February
                if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0) {
                     yield 29;  // is leap year
                } 
                yield 28;
    }
    default -> -1;
};
if (day < 1 || day > maxDay) {
    System.out.printf("Day(%d) is out of range for month(%d).", day, month);
}
```

If using `LocalDate`, the leap year will be checked also.  You could also use `Year.isLeap()` from the `java.time` package.  It is a package worth knowing about.